# Unable to open Ubuntu Software

Tags: command-line, system-installation, software-installation, video, software-center

I am new to Ubuntu and using it for my work. Now I have a problem in Ubuntu. Some time ago the **Ubuntu Software** showed me the updates and I updated it but since I updated it the **Ubuntu Software** does not open. Whenever I open the Ubuntu software, the loading icon appears at the top of the screen and closes automatically.

I read a lot of documentation about this but none of it worked for me and **now I'm very confused.**

When installing Ubuntu, I did not connect to the Internet to download the necessary packages, now I think that some of my problems (for example, not playing movies, not installing some programs in the terminal and **not running Software installer**) are because of this. How can I solve these problems?

Comment: edit your question to mention you have snap-store or gnome-software or other softwar center

Comment: may be you select minimal installation  so  install full ubuntu desktop

Comment: I have read many sources and tried the suggested commands but unfortunately they didn't work.

Comment: sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Even with this command, Ubuntu software still won't open for me

Comment: Basic starting point I look for in a question is details of the software stack being used; the question mentions Ubuntu, but not what Ubuntu product, what release etc.  Is this a Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Core? (Ubuntu Software would imply desktop, but we don't know for sure & have no idea of release). If disk is full, apps can refused to open on desktop systems so was sufficient disk space allocated as per documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to list snaps:

```
sudo snap list
```

the output like this:

```
Name                       Version           Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare                       1.0               5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20                     20230613          1950   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core22                     20230612          766    latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-38-2004            0+git.6f39565     140    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511   1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store                 41.3-71-g709398e  959    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
snapd                      2.59.5            19457  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9               83     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
```

remove all:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store snapd-desktop-integration gtk-common-themes
sudo snap remove  core22
sudo snap remove  bare
sudo snap remove  gnome-3-38-2004
sudo snap remove  core20
sudo snap remove  snapd
sudo apt reinstall snapd
```

install snap store:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
sudo snap install gnome-42-2204
sudo snap install snapd-desktop-integration
```

list the new snaps:

```
sudo snap list
```

you will see:

```
Name                       Version           Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
bare                       1.0               5      latest/stable  canonical✓  base
core22                     20230612          766    latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gnome-42-2204              0+git.ff35a85     111    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511   1535   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snap-store                 41.3-71-g709398e  959    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd                      2.59.5            19457  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9               83     latest/stable  canonical✓  -
```

now you can open ubuntu softwar

Comment: My system has core18 and doesn't remove.
snapd doesn't remove for me:
`error: cannot remove "snapd": snap "snapd" is not removalble: remove all other snaps first`

When I try to run the installation commands, I get the following error:
`error: cannot install "snap-store": cannot query the store for updates: got unexpected HTTP status code 408 via POST to "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh"`
Now the packages are removed for me and won't install

Comment: `sudo snap list` , remove one by one , if `error: cannot remove` try other snap remov. let `snapd` at the end.